# How to update SharePoint 2013 Office Web Apps: arguments for New-OfficeWebAppsFarm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-web-apps, owa

I have development, test, and production SharePoint 2013 farms, all with Office Web Apps (OWA) 2013 servers connected to each.

I want to apply the May 2013 OWA update but the process [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj966220.aspx) says to "remove the Office Web Apps Server that you want to apply the software update to from the load balancer pool" and "create an updated Office Web Apps Server farm by using the cmdlet New-OfficeWebAppsFarm" using "the same additional parameters that you used when you first created the Office Web Apps Server farm."

I don't have those parameters; OWA was installed by a consultant who is no longer here.

How can I generate the New-OfficeWebAppsFarm command from my existing farm prior to updating?

-Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the command `Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm` and copy the entire block. Use that for your `New-OfficeWebAppsFarm` going forward. The important parameters are:

```
-InternalURL
-ExternalURL
-CertificateName
-AllowHTTP
-EnableEditing
```

Comment: Edit: forgot one -- Enable Editing